# Resharper CLT InspectCode with Unity: Method 'Awake' is never used

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resharper, rider, code-inspection

I have Unity project and CI job to check code quality with Resharper InspectCode. Codestyle settings are in team-shared .dotSettings file.

This command runs Resharper Inspector on CI:

```
/JetBrains/inspectcode.sh project.sln --no-swea -o=inspection_results.xml --severity="WARNING" -x=JetBrains.Unity
```

**Question:** How can I ignore Unity Monobehavior lifecycle calls like `Awake`, `Start`, `Update`, `OnEnable` etc.? Inspection results always show this warnings:

```
<Issue TypeId="UnusedMember.Local" File="Assets\Scripts\Script.cs" Offset="955-960" Line="29" Message="Method 'Awake' is never used" />
<Issue TypeId="UnusedMember.Local" File="Assets\Scripts\Script.cs" Offset="1193-1199" Line="41" Message="Method 'Update' is never used" />
```

At the same time Rider doesn't show this warnings. Why Resharper CLT do?

```
JetBrains Inspect Code 2022.2.2
JetBrains Unity 2022.2.0.143
```

Comment: Resharper isn’t as good at telling what unity methods are triggered by unity

Comment: as far as I understand unity plugin is responsible for this

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-80879/Fix-zone-issue-with-Unity-plugin-for-CLT